# Where can I find the standard Visual C++ header files?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, header-files

Can I get an isolated collection of C/C++ standard header files from the Internet, without the requirement to install a development toolkit? I find it easy to get help from MSDN, but impossible to get the source files. For example, [here is a list on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/library/a7tkse1h.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the same that you are looking for in chinese but in english

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a7tkse1h.aspx

And no, you cant download it from the web either

So how to get the headers?  You have to install at least a redistributable C++ and do a search in the hard drive to find the location of the headers, search for a common header like String.h or Math.h

If you didnt need the headers from VC++ and you only want any headers you should go to

https://gcc.gnu.org/mirrors.html

pick one and search for the libstdc folder, there are the headers, for example:

ftp://gd.tuwien.ac.at/gnu/gcc/libstdc++/old-libg++-releases/iostream-0.62.tar.bz2

Will give you the iostream headers (file, fstream, iostream or ostream among others)